# Swift Interstitial is working, but once the ad is closed, I am still on gameboardVC. I need it to transition to gameOverVC, but I can't work out how

Tags: swift, admob, viewcontroller, interstitial

// MARK: - GAMEBOARD CONTROLLER
class GameBoard3: UIViewController,GADBannerViewDelegate,GADFullScreenContentDelegate

{
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

// MARK: - GAME OVER
func gameOver() {

```
    // Save Best Score
    if bestScore <= score3 {
        bestScore = score3
        UserDefaults.standard.set(bestScore, forKey: "bestScore")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
    
    // Play a sound
    soundName3 = "gameOver"
    playWav()
  
    
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       let goVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GameOverVC3")
       //self.present(myVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    if interstitial != nil {
      interstitial!.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    } else {
        self.present(goVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if interstitial != nil is true you will never call

```
self.present(goVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

i dont know if it will work to just copy the line too under

```
interstitial!.present(fromRootViewController: self)
```

or if you some how have to detect when the user dismisses the add

Comment: Thank you. If I reverse the order then the gameOver view appears fine but ad fails to show.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check delegate method `adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_:)` ?

In this callback you can whatever you want, for example redirect user to another screen.

Check the AdMob docs here: [Register for Callbacks](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial#register_for_callbacks)

Comment: Hi and thanks. The ad dismisses correctly, but the view doesn't transition to the gameOverVC.  I can't work out how to redirect user to another screen once the ad is dismissed.

Comment: @BEANETTA You should be good to go with just a few lines of code, where you instantiate your needed View Controller and push it onto the stack or present it, as you need. Basically you can do this: https://gist.github.com/petrkahanek/4a64f940c06ea80bab80e27a038d123f